# We are currently investigating an issue with the service you are attempting to reach - Google Cloud Platform - Support - Cases

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In the Google Cloud Platform > Support > Cases
I'm getting the error message:

> We are currently investigating an issue with the service you are attempting to reach

[image: Cloud Platform Cases Error]

But when I visit the Cloud Status Dashboard, there are no service disruptions.  And if I create a case, then it fails to be submitted.

[image: Cloud Platform case create action failed]

Am I filling out the information wrong, or is this an issue on Google's part?

Comment: this is a problem on their side - perhaps reach out to them via social media.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a problem with google's service.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use the "Emergency Contact Form" and submit a support request.  Because I have a Role Based support plan, I think that the member who submits a support request needs to have a role added that allows them to *make* the support request.  If I find out for sure, I'll provide a definitive answer.